# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable - it worked firstly, now I don't know what should be changed

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, error-handling, typeerror

I used this script to number my resulted values and to arrange these values from the lowest to highest. For me it is weird that it worked at beginning and printed the results as I wanted, but then when I tried it again it returns this error "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable"

```
rmsfer = RMSF(calphas).run()
sorted = sorted(range(len(rmsfer.rmsf)), key=lambda k: rmsfer.rmsf[k])
for x in range(len(rmsfer.rmsf)): 
    print(str(sorted[x] + 1) + '\t' + str(rmsfer.rmsf[sorted[x]]))
```

And the result should looked like this:

```
105 0.3314483229352872
100 0.3397965717595412
104 0.3554166855598925
17  0.35772971838887907
51  0.3593822683383331
50  0.3727401709799276
```

Now when I try it reproduce with exactly the same script and inputs (the same jupyter notebook) it returns me that type error.

Comment: Think about the first part of this line carefully `sorted = sorted(range(len(rmsfer.rmsf))... `

Comment: Changing it to brackets?

Comment: `sorted = sorted(...` overwrites the name `sorted`. `sorted` no longer refers to the function after that; it instead refers to the list. Change that variable name to something else so it doesn't override the built-in function.

Comment: I deleted that line completely and it works again"! Thanks for suggestions. The only thing I dont get is why it worked before

Comment: It works the first time because before `sorted = sorted(...` runs, `sorted` is the function. After that runs though, `sorted` is the list. If this worked before, then you had this code in a more enclosed scope or something. Your local `sorted` was going out of scope at some point.